# Merging all changesets associated with a WorkItem in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs, workitem

We're trailing the use of the built in bug tracking, and have written some integration into our helpdesk software that allows for escalation via workitems.

One thing I haven't found out how to do, is to merge all changes associated with a work item (say to go from dev branch to main) - I appreciate you can double click on a changeset in the merge dialog to view if it is associated with a workitem, and also that I can select individual changesets, and groups of adjacent changesets; but there doesn't appear to be any way to merge changes by workitem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct that you can't merge based on work items. It is probably not a good idea to do that anyway. It would be very difficult to make sure you get all the necessary changes needed for the main branch to build correctly. I would look into how you do your branching and a good starting point would be: [Microsoft Team Foundation Server Branching Guidance](http://www.codeplex.com/BranchingGuidance)

In TFS 2005 and 2008 the check in history will not be transferred between branches. You will get this in TFS 2010.

Comment: So what stratergy are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Merge changesets by workitem - https://tfsprod.codeplex.com/
Check out the ExtendedMerge feature.

Enjoy! :)